# How do I put Vue chunk files in public/js with Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel and Vue project in which I'm using dynamic `import` function calls in the Vue to chunk my components into separate files.

Everything's working fine, but the Vue chunk files (e.g., `0.js`, `1.js`, etc.) are being placed directly under the `public` directory, instead of under `public/js`, which is where `app.js` is.

Here is my Laravel Mix file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
   .sass('resources/sass/vendor.scss', 'public/css/')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/')
   .version();
```

What do I need to change/add to get the Vue chunk files to be automatically placed within `public/js` when I build every time, instead of directly under the `public` directory? Thanks.

Comment: i add exactly the same thing, i'm kind of new on vue and laravel-mix concept. if i need to deploy the app in production, should i need to make a npm install and npm run prod ? i was thinking that app.js contains the chunks files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the path in webpack like following

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js',//replace with your path
    },
});
```

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1309) for more information

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.